# Is it possible to import a PNG file into SAS to include in RTF output?

Tags: sas, sas-ods

I have PNG files that were created outside of SAS that I would like to include in an RTF file that I will output from SAS using ODS.  Is it possible to use SAS to do this?  My internet searches are turning up a lot of irrelevant results.

Comment: This seems to be relevant: page 10, http://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings11/263-2011.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ODS RTF: The Basics And Beyond](http://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings11/263-2011.pdf), is certainly relevant.  Here's an example of doing this in body text not using the title.

```
ods rtf file="c:\temp\test.rtf" startpage=never;
ods escapechar='^';
proc print data=sashelp.class;
run;
ods text='^S={preimage="C:\temp\SGPlot.jpeg" just=c}';
proc print data=sashelp.class;
run;
ods rtf close;
```

That's using a random SGPLOT I had laying around, but of course you can use whatever you prefer.  I added `startpage=never` to have it put things on the same page - but of course that's optional (otherwise it'll put the image on its own page in my example).

The important thing is the `ods text` (which puts some text, normally), the `ods escapechar` (which sets `^` to be the escape character), and then `^S={ }` which is how you insert styles and similar things in RTF (and other destinations).  Then we just use `preimage` which means put an image before the next bit (the text, which is blank here).  You could just as easily have put this in the `title` statement, rather than `ods text`, if that's where you want the image.

Comment: Thanks, Joe.  This gets me most of the way there.  What I'm still missing is that the output now creates a cell that is as tall as the image with zero width.  When I expand the cell I can see my image. I'm not sure what I'm still missing.