# Insert image into PDF SAS

Tags: image, pdf, sas, ods

I am properly confused, I am trying to get my head around ODS PDF. I don't need it to look pretty, I just need to insert an image of a statistical formula.

```
ODS PDF FILE="&exceldir\README.pdf";
TITLE "DATA INDEX FOR &STUDY";
ODS PDF TEXT = "blah blah blah";

a great image of how to calculate standard deviation or something.

ODS PDF TEXT = "blah blah blah";
ODS PDF CLOSE;
```

I am struggling to find a way to do this, any help would be greatly appreciated.

J

Comment: Please refer to  [Joe's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31303403/is-it-possible-to-import-a-png-file-into-sas-to-include-in-rtf-output) on Importing an Image into `SAS` to include in `RTF` file. This really helps.

Comment: I did not know that RTF syntax was usable for PDF, thanks for your help this worked.

Comment: No problem @JasonRogers .Glad it worked :)

Comment: @PraneethKumar Thanks for pointing out the link!  In the future feel free to "flag" questions that are basically duplicates of other questions, that is one of the close reasons available in that dialog.  (This is what I did, but I have extra powers to do it instantly; you'd just be "suggesting" it as a possibility and OP would have the choice to agree or not.)

Comment: Sure @Joe , point noted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer:

```
ODS PDF FILE="&exceldir\README.pdf";
TITLE "DATA INDEX FOR &STUDY";
ODS PDF TEXT = "blah blah blah";
ODS ESCAPECHAR='^';
ODS TEXT='^S={preimage="P:\MEAN.PNG" just=c}';
ODS PDF TEXT = "blah blah blah";
ODS PDF CLOSE;
```